# How can I reorganize the menu layout in Hugo?

Tags: layout, hugo

I'm relatively new to Hugo and mostly just using default values. The current theme provides Personas and Tags as taxonomy categories, and they appear at the bottom of the menu system in the left navigation bar. I know how to use weight to change the order of the other menus, etc., but I'd like to put these taxonomy categories at the top.

I've been reading through the .toml file, Hugo docs, etc., but I'm not a coder and some of it is hard to understand. Any suggestions on how I can do this? thanks.

Using hugo-0.69.0-2.fc32~bootstrap.x86_64